# Formulário PHP, como redirecionar com os dados preenchidos?

Tags: php, html

estou com uma dúvida, e irei explicar. Estou terminando um site de uma clínica de exames, só que lá não é possível marcar exames, tendo que redirecionar para outro site. No meu site existe um campo para preencher, o de "Senha" e um botão de "ok", após a digitação da senha e o click no botão, o site é redirecionado para outro que faz o agendamento. Este outro site possui dois campos o de "Unidade" (que abre um dropdown com varias unidades médicas" e o de "Senha". Eu gostaria que ao redirecionar para este outro site, o campo Unidade já esteja preenchido com a unidade que eu quero, e com a senha que foi digitada no site anterior.

```
<form name="form1" method="post"
action="http://www.laudosonline.com.br/listalaudos.php" target = "_blank">
<input name="codnegoper" type="hidden" id="90|1" value="90|1" />
<input name="senha" type="password" value="" size="20" maxlength="20">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

me passaram este formulário apenas, desculpe as informações razas eu sou estagiário e me pediram para fazer isto. Ja agradeço pela atenção de todos !

Comment: input codnegoper é o campo  que guarda o valor que faz referência da unidade da clínica?

Comment: Olá Vitor, você tem acesso ao código da página que vai receber esses dados?

Comment: Olha o outro website é seu? se for da para passar esses dados pela url e tratar nos inputs do lado de la, mas se não for acredito que não dará certo! primeiro pq tu esta enviando um post para uma url externa e dependendo da forma que o sistema de laudos foi desenvolvido ele deve ter uma proteção contra posts que não venham da pagina dele...

Comment: olá Matheus !, então eu preciso ver com meu chefe quando ele chegar, mas eu creio que não, eu consigo fazer isso sem o codigo da outra página ?

Comment: desculpem pela informação raza, acabei de ver, esse form é do site que está redirecionando

Comment: Vitor, explica melhor a situação dos dois sites, quais dele tu tem acesso para podermos entender qual a melhor maneira de solucionar o teu problema.

Comment: Consegui as informações, esse formulário é do site que faz o agendamento, ou seja, o site 2, eu tenho que pegar as informações do site 1 (no caso a senha) e redirecionar ao site 2 e preencher automaticamente a senha digitada no site anterior, além de selecionar automaticamente a unidade. Eu possuo acesso aos dois sites. Estava pesquisando em fazer pelo metodo GET, ou pelo POST que é mais seguro, só que nao sei fazer pelo POST

Comment: Se eles estiverem em servidores diferentes, tu precisa habilitar o CROSS DOMAIN no servidor que irá receber, somente desta maneira tu consegue fazer um POST para outro servidor. Caso seja esse o caso, sugiro que passe via GET as informações.

Answer (score -1):

Bem o único jeito de fazer isso seria fazendo a requisição com Javascript, assim quando você apertasse no botão de ok chamaria uma função no Javascript que enviaria seus dados e não zeraria seur form, seria mais ou menos assim.

No form

```
<button id="enviar">Ok</button>
```

E no js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        //Pega os dados e envia
    })
</script>
```

o event.preventDefault() vai fazer com que a ação do botão dentro do form não aconteça